# New instance of Word acts as a child process to existing hosted Word application

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, ms-word

I am working on a Word automation tool, where I host Word in a WPF window. I use the following code to create a new Word application

```
    // Initialize handle value to invalid
    appWin = IntPtr.Zero;

    // Start the remote application
    try
        {
            // Start the process
            if (_wordApp == null) _wordApp = new ApplicationClass();
            _wordApp.Application.Caption = WORD_APP_NAME;

            //find the process
            appWin = FindWindow("Opusapp", _wordApp.Application.Caption);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(this, ex.Message, "Error");
        }           

        // Put it into this form
        SetParent(appWin, this.Handle);
```

on closing the application I want all the spawned Word apps to be killed.

```
    protected override void OnHandleDestroyed(EventArgs e)
    {
        // Stop the application
        if (appWin != IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            // to be sure that the word app closes without trace 
            try
            {
                uint pid;
                uint pid2 = GetWindowThreadProcessId(appWin,out pid);

                Process proc = Process.GetProcessById((int)pid);
                proc.Kill();
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                //write logs.
            }
            _wordApp = null;

            // Clear internal handle
            appWin = IntPtr.Zero;
        }
        base.OnHandleDestroyed (e);
    }
```

The problem is that when a user uses this application and opens a new Word document in parallel, the new Word acts as a child process of the present process, hence on killing the process The new Word app is closed as well.

How can I make sure that the Word app I use is always a different process than any other Word application currently running or opened later.

Comment: You don't need to kill the process. It's enough to keep a reference to the word Application that you create and then call its Quit method.

Comment: This question still has no good answer. I want to KEEP a background process dedicated to the software because it's faster to use it that way in that framework, but if I open another Word externally it opens the internal process.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to kill the process. It's enough to keep a reference to the word [`Application`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.office.interop.word.application(v=office.15).aspx) that you create and then call its [`Quit`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.office.interop.word._application.quit(v=office.15).aspx) method.

For example:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
static extern IntPtr SetParent(IntPtr hWndChild, IntPtr hWndNewParent);

Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application word;

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    word = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
    var documents = word.Documents;
    documents.Open(@"d:\file1.docx");
    SetParent(new IntPtr(word.ActiveWindow.Hwnd), this.Handle);
    word.Visible = true;
}
private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    if (word != null)
        word.Quit();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you not store the process id of the Word instance you're spawning, and then on shutdown close only that process (use Process.GetProcesses() to iterate through the running processes, matching them with the process id you've stored)

Comment: I am doing exactly the same, in the code above i only kill the process which i started, the issue is that when the user opens a word application (lets say by clicking word icon on desktop) there is no new process created, the same process handles my hosted app and new application.

Comment: ok - isn't there some way via the ApplicationClass to discern between Word instances spawned by you and the user i.e. can you subscribe to an event when a new document is added ?

Comment: The ApplicationClass has a Windows property that lists the collection of windows in the application (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.windows.aspx) - can you iterate through that and Close the appropriate Window object ?